# Caveat with C++11 inherited constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement

> For base-class constructors, C++11 allows a class to specify that base
>   class constructors will be inherited. Thus, the C++11 compiler will
>   generate code to perform the inheritance and the forwarding of the
>   derived class to the base class. This is an all-or-nothing feature:
>   either all of that base class's constructors are forwarded or none of
>   them are. Also, restrictions exist for multiple inheritance, such that
>   class constructors cannot be inherited from two classes that use
>   constructors with the same signature. **Nor can a constructor in the
>   derived class exist that matches a signature in the inherited base
>   class.**

Can someone give me an example to illustrate the issue with "***Nor can a constructor in the derived class exist that matches a signature in the inherited base class.***"?

Comment: I fixed the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 6):

It means that if you have constructor in the derived class whose parameter list matches the parameter list of *any* constructor in the base class, then that derived class' constructor is taken and **hides** the base class'

E.g.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo(){std::cout << "Foo default ctor\n";}
   Foo(int){std::cout << "Foo(int)\n";}
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   using Foo::Foo;
   Bar(int){std::cout << "Bar\n";} // won't implicitly call Foo(int)
};

int main()
{
    Bar b(1);
}
```

From §12.9/3 [class.inhctor] (Emphasis mine):

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors other than a constructor
>   having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly
>   declared with the same constructor characteristics **unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor would be a default,
>   copy, or move constructor for that class**.

Comment: the OP doesn't compile and I made some changes. The code shows it still can inherit Foo's constructor. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63e36a2c70f2d602

Comment: @q0987: Sorry, updated. I needed to take a closer look at the standard to get it right.